# Android can't show notification

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, notifications, broadcastreceiver

I'm using the NotificationService and a Broadcastreceiver to get the incoming notifications. The service starts from the manifest:

```
<service android:name="com.myapp.notifications.MyNotificationListenerService"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">

            <intent-filter>

                <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />

            </intent-filter>

        </service>
```

and it's this;

```
public class MyNotificationListenerService extends NotificationListenerService{
    Context context;

    @Override

    public void onCreate() {

        super.onCreate();
        context = getApplicationContext();

    }
    @Override

    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {


        String pack = sbn.getPackageName();
        String ticker = sbn.getNotification().tickerText.toString();
        Bundle extras = sbn.getNotification().extras;
        String title = extras.getString("android.title");
        String text = extras.getCharSequence("android.text").toString();

        Log.i("Package",pack);
        Log.i("Ticker",ticker);
        Log.i("Title",title);
        Log.i("Text",text);

        Intent msgrcv = new Intent("Msg");
        msgrcv.putExtra("package", pack);
        msgrcv.putExtra("ticker", ticker);
        msgrcv.putExtra("title", title);
        msgrcv.putExtra("text", text);

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(msgrcv);


    }

    @Override

    public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        Log.i("Msg","Notification Removed");

    }
}
```

When a notification arrives the log shows me the title, the package and the other informations correctly.. The problem is this one;

I have an Activity that is the MainActivity in which i have the  NavigationDrawer. The class where i want show the incoming notifications is a Fragment! So i created in the MainActivity the Broadcastreceiver and then i inflate with `LayoutInflater` the layout of the fragment to get all component i need in this way:

```
public BroadcastReceiver onNotice= new BroadcastReceiver() {
        LinearLayout notificationLayout;
        Drawable icon;

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String pack = intent.getStringExtra("package");
            String title = intent.getStringExtra("title");
            String text = intent.getStringExtra("text");

            LayoutInflater mInf = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            View myView = mInf.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
            notificationLayout = (LinearLayout)myView.findViewById(R.id.notificationLayout);
            TextView notificationDescription = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.notificationDesc);
            TextView notificationTitle = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.notificationTitle);
            CircularImageView notificationImage = (CircularImageView) myView.findViewById(R.id.img_thumbnail);

            Toast.makeText(DrawerActivity.this, title, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if(!pack.equals("") || !title.equals("") || !text.equals("")) {
                notificationLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                notificationTitle.setText(title);
                notificationDescription.setText(text);

                try {
                    icon = DrawerActivity.this.getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(pack);
                } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                notificationImage.setImageDrawable(icon);

            } else {
                notificationLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

        }
    };
```

When the notification arrives now appears the Toast that notify me the title of the notification but i can't see the values in the view.. the layout of the notification is empty.. How is possible?

Or how can i put the values from the activity to my fragment?

Comment: Just to clear issue. When you add inflated layout to fragmets root View?

Answer (score 0):

Whne you inflate a layout, it creates a new tree made up of new objects.

The way to accomplish what you are trying to would be to cache whatever views that you will change in your `onCreate` and refer to them in your BroadcastReceiver's `onReceive`.

```
private TextView textView;
private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //TODO: Update Views
    }
};

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);

    //Cache views
    textView = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.textview);

    return root;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    getActivity().registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, filter);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    getActivity().unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
}
```

Comment: mm, how can i change my code right now if i follow your suggestion? Can you show me please?

Comment: Is your fragment always going to be persistent in the activity? When do you add it?

Comment: i call it in the onNavigationItemSelected of the navdrawer:

`setNewRootFragment(Fragment.newInstance());`

i just find a way to put the values in there..Or if there is a way to put the Breadcastreceiver in the Fragment directly.. I also tried that way but the Br not started..

Comment: Why not? Where did you register it? I think it would be best to handle it in the `onResume` and `onPause`.

Comment: i tried in onResume()..how would you like to call it in the fragment?

Comment: what is filter when you register the br?

Comment: you mean like: new IntentFilter("Msg");?

Comment: Yes. If you're doing a local broadcast, you should be able to do the same thing, btw: `LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, filter);`

Comment: using only registerReceiver not works.. now i try         LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(onNotice, filter1);

Comment: not works :( nothing shows..from the activity the toast showed and the br started..from frsgment nope

Comment: shortly, i have two possibilities; 1) Start the breadcastreceiver from the activity of the navDrawer (the only activity i have that fires the fragments) and inflate the layout of the fragment to put the values in there! 2) Start the Broadcast from the fragment but i seems not works with your solution. If i use the 1 way i can see the toast inside the Broadcast with all information i need but i can't put them in the layout and i don't know why.. Maybe i'mk wrong with inflate